# AVD manager & SDK Manager won't work

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, android-sdk-tools

What's wrong? I just installed an Android Studio bundle which installed AVD & SDK manager respectively. But when I run them a console window opens for a second or less and then vanishes and neither the AVD not the SDK manager runs. I have java and JDK installed. Interestingly, I found another copy of AVD manager and SDK manager in the "\android-sdk\tools" directory. Now when I ran these, I get an error saying "cannot run tools\android.bat.
The system cannot find the file path specified," I need help immediately. I'm at the moment scratching my head for making this work. I tried repairing, uninstalling and reinstalling but nothing helped. I checked out some other stackoverflow posts but they didn't help me either.

Comment: Add your PC brand and Operating system in your Q